# LVM2 Mirror Support Missing from Kernel after System Migration

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, lvm, migration

I had a system that was running on a small netbook that had LVM2 set up to group two external USB hard drives into a volume group, and to use that volume group to create a mirrored logical volume.

Then I wanted to migrate to a better machine, so I copied the disk image to a better laptop, and booted. All good so far. I can get LVM to recognize the two attached USB hard drives, and to recognize that they're LVM-enabled, and to recognize that they're part of the same volume group. I can export and import that volume group. However, when I try to enable it (`vgchange -ay vg_mirror`), I get the following error and output:

> Can't process LV lv_mirror: mirror target support missing from kernel?
>
> 0 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg_mirror" now active

I've tried uninstalling (both `apt-get uninstall` and `apt-get purge`) and reinstalling to no avail. I'm running a 686 kernel on an Intel Core i3, so I doubt that's the issue, although I can't figure out why switching machines would have borked any kernel drivers other than an instruction set or hardware incompatability. Any ideas?

Comment: What versions of LVM and distros are we dealing w/ here? Sounds like you're missing a kernel module on the 2nd system or the LVM isn't current.

Comment: `lvm version`: `LVM version: 2.02.95(2) (2012-03-06); Library version: 1.02.83 (2013-11-13)`

Comment: `uname -a`: `Linux hostname 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 i686 GNU/Linux`

Comment: And I seriously doubt it's a missing kernel module or a non-current LVM. This exact setup worked perfectly on the old machine - I literally copied the disk contents verbatim (classic old `dd if=/dev/old of=/dev/new` style).

Comment: Fair enough, I'm simply following the path of error messages to that conclusion. But I'm in agreement w/ you, that doesn't fit what you're describing so let's throw that out.

Comment: Here check this out: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/58510

Comment: Yeah, I mean I get where you're coming from. Without knowing that it's a clone, that'd definitely be the first thing to check.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can adapt that solution; my issue is mirroring, not merging. Maybe a similar root cause, but their solution seems pretty merge-specific.

Comment: Yeah I didn't dig enough, check this section out: https://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/scientific6/docs/rhel/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/#mirrorrecover. I would read this several times to make sure it makes sense and that you understand it thoroughly, from the looks of it you could damage your LVM if you don't.

Comment: hahaha fun... I'll check it out.

Comment: If you figure it out, don't hesitate to self A your Q.